# Mongo doesn't start on fresh install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, installation

After installing mongodb on 14.04, mongo doesn't work out of the box:

```
$ sudo apt install mongodb-server
[...]
$ sudo start mongodb  
mongodb stop/waiting
```

What's happening here, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: change `no` to `yes` in `/etc/default/mongodb` and restart the service**

The interesting part is in the upstart script (`/etc/init/mongodb.conf`), at line 19 and 21:

```
[...]
script
    ENABLE_MONGODB="yes"
    if [ -f /etc/default/mongodb ]; then
        . /etc/default/mongodb
    fi
    if [ "$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "yes" ]; then
        exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid mongodb \
            --exec /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb.conf
    fi
end script
```

So if `ENABLE_MONGODB` is `yes`, mongod starts and everything is good. It is set to `yes` in the script, but `/etc/default/mongodb` is sourced.

A peek inside `/etc/default/mongodb` shows the problem:

```
ENABLE_MONGODB="no"
```

I don't know why this ships disabled, change it to `yes` and you'll be fine after a `sudo restart mongodb`.

Comment: Maybe a bug in the latest package?

Comment: subsequent research has suggested this might be an intentional disabling of the package at install time. Which is insane.

Comment: I don't see that file on my server.